# What is the recommended way to synchronize music on an Android phone?

Tags: wi-fi, sync, music

I have a server which is on all the time, on a network share I store my music collection. I would like to synchronize this with my phone. If I add new album on my server it should pop up on my phone and vice-versa

What software would I need to support the following requirements to synchronize music to my phone?

- Should run on Android 2.3
- Should run on Windows 7
- Can synchronize over wifi
- Should work in the United Kingdom
- Two-way sychronization from pc - phone and phone - pc

Comment: In general questions that ask for the "best" method or for lists of answers are discouraged.  I would suggest enumerating criteria that would make for a good solution (WiFi sync, two-way sync or something like that, other features) and asking if there is a solution that meets those criteria.

Comment: fair point, i'll try and make the question more succinct

Comment: Good edit, @Edward.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure the list is long, but i'll mention what I've found after a brief investigation and from other answers

## Syncness

[image]

http://www.clayworldsoftware.com/index.php/syncness/

- Sync with multiple shares on your home or work network
- Sync with mutilple Dropbox accounts
- Two way file deletions
- Sync when wifi network is detected! - thats very cool
- Scheduled sync

**Pros**

- Syncing on detecting the wifi network
- Doesn't require a server application running on a PC
- Quite cheap $1.99

**Cons**

- Doesn't do media conversion Missing sync does

## Google Music

[image: Google music logo]

http://music.google.com/music/

**Pros**

**Cons**

Only available to users in the United States

## Winamp

http://www.winamp.com/android

[image]

Seems possible to sync over wifi using both a winamp client on the phone and pc
http://blog.winamp.com/2010/11/30/wirelessly-sync-music-to-your-android-phone/

**Pros**

Free!

## Missing Sync

http://www.markspace.com/products/missing-sync-family.html
[image: missing sync gallery picture]

**Pros**

Seems to have quite a comprehensive set of two-way synchronization features. Supports wifi and multiple devices, quite handy as I have an iphone as well

**Cons**

Cost $39.95

Comment: Never got the wifi syncing to work on my phone, and having the wifi option turned on cause my phone to drain its battery within 2 hours. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

There are various options.

I actually use Windows Media Player.  It actually does a pretty good job syncing, although I'm not fond of the interface in general. I use [PowerAmp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer&feature=search_result) to play my music, but any player should work.  This does require a cable however.

[AirSync](http://www.doubletwist.com/airsync/) syncs your playlist over the air.  It sounds convenient but it costs $4.99, but since you want it over Wifi that may do the job.

You can also use the [Amazon MP3 Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.amazon.mp3&feature=search_result) if you want to load your music onto the cloud, or one of the other cloud services that have been suggested so far.

Comment: +1 for AirSync, I like their implementation.

Answer (score 2):

### [Google Music](http://music.google.com)

Google Music puts music from your PC onto Google servers which you can access from your phone. It has a save-to-phone option, playlists and other features.

Comment: Yep. It works great for those of us up in Canada... :(

Answer (score 1):

It's a paid app but I've found [Syncness](https://market.android.com/details?id=clay.world.syncness&feature=search_result) to be good. It allows multiple sync profiles, sync on connect to particular Wifi networks or time based syncs.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use Style Jukebox.

It's similar to Google Music, only that it's cross-platform and has app for Windows too.
You get Style Jukebox for your computer and any song you add there will be automatically uploaded to your Cloud account. You can upload up to 2000 songs for free.

Then with any device you have (Android, WP or iOS) you can instantly access your music and playlists, from anywhere.

www.get-jukebox.com

Comment: Are you affiliated with the developer of Jukebox? If so, please mention that in your answer.